# Removing /**/ from html using python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, nlp

This is the code I am trying to skip which is in Multiple Lines.

> /****/
>       if (window.bbcdotcom && bbcdotcom.slot) {
>       bbcdotcom.slot('mpu', [1,2,3]);
>       }
>       /**/
>       
>       I tried BeautifulSoup, My Best of Knowledge and also regex but am not able to get it to work properly. I am beginner in python & trying to get some content using RSS Feed & perform Natural Language Processing.

Comment: Are they guaranteed to be on the same line, and unbroken by spaces or anything else?

Comment: Probably not. Also, show some code please.

Comment: They are not in same line & the code is same that i presented here (except the first line is/**/ comments).
Thanks for the reply. I handled my issue with lxml package.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the comments (`/*...*/`), you can use

```
p = re.compile(r'(?s)/\*.*?\*/')
result = re.sub(p, '', test_str)
```

To remove all text inside `/*...*/`, you can use

```
p = re.compile(ur'(?s)/\*.*?\*/.*?/\*.*?\*/')
result = re.sub(p, '', test_str)
```

[Complete sample code](http://ideone.com/ce0Wp7):

```
import re
test_str = u"/****/\n\n      if (window.bbcdotcom && bbcdotcom.slot) {\n      bbcdotcom.slot('mpu', [1,2,3]);\n      }\n      /**/\n      "
# REMOVE ALL BETWEEN COMMENTS AND THE COMMENTS THEMSELVES
p = re.compile(r'(?s)/\*.*?\*/.*?/\*.*?\*/')
result = re.sub(p, '', test_str)
print "Result 1: " + result
# REMOVE THE COMMENTS
p = re.compile(r'(?s)/\*.*?\*/')
result = re.sub(p, '', test_str)
print "Result 2: " + result
```

Output:

```
Result 1: 

Result 2: 

      if (window.bbcdotcom && bbcdotcom.slot) {
      bbcdotcom.slot('mpu', [1,2,3]);
      }
```

Comment: Please note that the regex suggested in the previous answer will also remove everything between just `//` (due to `*` quantifier used after the literal asterisk), which might be unsafe: see https://regex101.com/r/kU1rL5/1. My suggestion eliminates that issue, as `*` is required to appear at least once.

Comment: @Nithin, does it work for you or do you need more assistance with it?

Comment: I had the same issue by using it. So, I just moved from regex to lxml.by the way thanks.

Comment: You say you had an issue, but you did not state it in your question. I would update my answer if you provided exact input and expected output. Anyway. I am glad you found a solution.

Comment: Could you please include the information on the issue you had? I'd like to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the formatting is exactly as above, then a simple regex will suffice:

`"/\**/.*?/\**/"` -- basically, a slash followed by some stars and then a slash, followed by anything at all, up until a slash followed by stars and another slash. Use `re.sub` to replace that with nothing, and you'll have stripped it out of your text. See below, assuming all text is in the `text` variable.

```
import re

In [12]: re.sub("/\**/.*?/\**/", '', "/*****/ hi hello how are you /**/")
Out[12]: ''

In [13]: re.sub("/\**/.*?/\**/", '', "testing \n 1 2 3/*****/ hi hello how are y
ou /**/ and more testing...")
Out[13]: 'testing \n 1 2 3 and more testing...'
```